# Advice on reducing size of a pond with fill

Tags: pond

We have a large pond on our property that I'd like to reduce in size to make more "solid ground" space around it. We also have piles of broken concrete blocks / chunks of cement taking up lots of space.

I was thinking to dump the concrete fill in the pond and fill the voids of each layer with road crush until it's about a foot from the grade level, and fill that with whatever top soil.
I would put the biggest/flattest chunks at the bottom

I understand the issue is the soil might settle a bit after a while, hence the filling the voids between the blocks with road crush which should minimize that.

Does that sound like a good plan?